# Why does it not console.log anything when running findOne with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to Query my MongoDB with Mongoose.

I search for the string `13` in the field `eClassSegment` in the collection eclasses. Something is printed in the console. Why?

Code:

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
EClass              = require('./models/eclass');

mongoose.Promise    = require('bluebird');

EClass.findOne({ 'eClassSegment': '13' }, 'eClassSegment', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
    console.log('All eClassSegments that equals 13: ', result);
});
```

The Moongoose Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

// Defining Mongoose Schema
const eClassSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    eclassSegment: { type: String, min: 2, max: 2 },
    eclassMainGroup: { type: String, min: 2, max: 2 },
    eclassGroup: { type: String, min: 2, max: 2 },
    eclassCommodityClass: { type: String, min: 2, max: 2 },
    preferredName: { type: String, max: 80 },
    definition: { type: String, max: 1023 },
    level: { type: String, min: 1, max: 1 },
    mkSubclass: { type: String, min: 1, max: 1 },
    mkKeyword: { type: String, min: 1, max: 1 }
});

// Create mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('EClass', eClassSchema);
```

Example of an document in the MongoDB (I have many documents with `eClassSegment = '13'`..)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e5d8d8fc0788063e587e1a"),
    "mkKeyword" : "0",
    "mkSubclass" : "1",
    "level" : "1",
    "definition" : "Services for the development of a product basically on the basis of service contracts or contract development",
    "preferredName" : "Development (Service)",
    "eclassCommodityClass" : "00",
    "eclassGroup" : "00",
    "eclassMainGroup" : "00",
    "eclassSegment" : "13",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to connect to the database... Need some coffe... :-)

Here is the solution!

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose'),
    EClass          = require('./models/eclass');

mongoose.Promise    = require('bluebird');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/eclassCSV');

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
    var geteClass = function() {
        EClass.findOne({ 'eclassSegment': '13' }, 'eclassSegment', function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: ', err);
            }
            console.log('All eclassSegments that equals 13: ', result);
        })
        .then(function() {
            mongoose.disconnect();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('There was an error', err);
        });
    };
    geteClass();
});
```

Example of a Console.log of result

```
All eclassSegments that equals 13:  { _id: 58e5d8d8fc0788063e587e1a, eclassSegment: '13' }
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to search for `eClassSegment`.

But the key in the schema and the database is `eclassSegment`

Comment: Please `mark as Answer` if you are satified with the answer. :)

Comment: Thank you MegaMind for finding the typo. :-)

Comment: @MegaMind It's not polite to pressure the OP to upvote or select your answer.

Comment: @VinceBowdren noted :)